# dynamically dragging and connecting created nodes in angular6 with jsplumb

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, jsplumb

I'm trying to give to the user the ability to create, drag and connect multiple nodes but I still don't understand how angular render this or the life cycle of components and other, so even after a lot of research, I'm still unable to figure out how to fix the issues listed below.

Basically, I'm to trying to achieve what I already achieved with a simple HTML [page](https://jsfiddle.net/greenwa/tLyuszfh/11/), but this time [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb-test) with Angular and angular is not making it easy for me.
First I was struggling with making the new divs draggable, I managed to do that but now the endpoints do not seem to be able to connect, don't know why or how to fix it.
And even after checking out the doc I still don't understand how stuff in the code like `AfterViewInit`, `ComponentFactoryResolver`, `parentInjector`, `resolveComponentFactory` work, indeed they solved the draggability issue for me, but don't know why or how they fixed it.

So any help or explanation would reaaaaally appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are adding endpoints and making nodes draggable using new jsplumb instance created at the moment where that node component is created, 
which will result eventually in many jsplumb instances for every node, and that's what seems to be the problem cuz apparently to connect those nodes they must be initialized with the same jsplumb instance : So try creating just one instance (or use the default jsplumb instance) in the parent component (the one holding all the nodes) and then pass it with property binding (@input...) to the newly created nodes to use to become draggable etc.

Comment: thanks this got it working for me, I even removed the `ComponentFactoryResolver` and other stuff I wasn't sure how to use to make my code less complicated for me, and it's still working.

Comment: @user8097714 can you put here a link with jsfiddle to help others ?